# In a metric Lie algebra, is the orthogonal complement of a Lie subalgebra a Lie subalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a (finite-dimensional, real) Lie algebra equipped with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $\langle \cdot{,}\cdot \rangle$ that is *ad-invariant*, i.e., such that
\begin{equation*}
\langle [x,y],z\rangle = \langle x,[y,z]\rangle \quad \text{for all $x,y,z \in \mathfrak{g}$};
\end{equation*}
let $S$ be a nondegenerate subspace.

**Question**. Suppose that $S$ is closed under the Lie bracket, i.e., it is a Lie subalgebra. Does it then follow that its orthogonal complement $S^{\perp}$ (which is automatically nondegenerate) is also a Lie subalgebra?

I believe that, in general, the answer is *no*. However, it would be great if somebody could provide a counterexample.

Comment: A tangentially related question on nomenclature. Why is this property called 'ad-invariant'? Your definition tranlates to $\langle ad(y)x, z \rangle = - \langle x, ad(y)z \rangle$. Naively (going by the usual meaning of invariant) I would expect an ad-invariant bilinear form  to satisfy $\langle ad(y)x, z \rangle = - \langle x, ad(y)z \rangle$ so without the minus sign. At the same time I know your defnition is the standard one. So where does this odd situation (calling something invariant when in reality it gets a sign flip) come from?

Comment: @Vincent it is really $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant and skew for $\mathrm{ad}$ but  it's more convenient to use the same terminology across the Lie group and Lie algebra story. Same way we talk about normalisers in Lie algebras when by rights they should be called idealisers.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely not true. An important example of this is the Cartan decomposition of a semisimple Lie Algebra. These are decompositions of the form $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{k}$ is a maximal compact subalgebra (in other words a maximal subalgebra with negative definite Killing form).
Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is very far from being a subalgebra. In fact, $[\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{p}] \subset \mathfrak{k}$.

Note this works for any symmetric decomposition too.

For a simple Lie algebra the Killing form is the only ad-invariant, nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form up to scale. So unless the Lie algebra is compact there is no definite (positive or negative) form with those properties. Thus, "orthogonal complement" is a bit of a dodgy concept. The orthogonal subspace may overlap with the original so it can't be called complementary in general (the Cartan decomposition is an important exception).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply! Why do you say that "the orthogonal subspace may overlap with the original"? This does not happen if the subspace is nondegenerate

Comment: Ah I had missed that line. Yes for non-degenerate subalgebras they will have orthocomplements. My example still stands though :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: As an additional point if we are talking about semsimple Lie algebras (which the admission of such a form I think implies) then a decomposition into two orthogonal subalgebras can only be breaking it up into its smaller semsimple pieces. So there are only a finite number of ways where that can happen. Meanwhile, there are whole orbits worth of symmetric/reductive decompositions where this breaks.

Answer (score 6):

Take $\mathfrak{g} = \mathbb{R}^3$ with $[x,y] = x \times y$ the cross product and as symmetric bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the usual scalar product. Then the space $S = \langle e_1 \rangle$ is closed under the Lie bracket and $S^\perp = \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle$ but $e_2 \times e_3 = e_1$.